# How to delete connection by name via Network Manager

Tags: networkmanager

How do you use `nmcli` to delete a wifi connection by name?

From what I've read, it only allows deletion via UUID:

```
nmcli connection delete <uuid>
```

The simplest way I've found to delete by name is to lookup the UUID from the name and pass that in:

```
nmcli con delete `nmcli --fields NAME,UUID con list | grep -i mynetworkname | awk '{print $2}'`
```

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 37):

To delete a wifi connection type :

```
nmcli connection delete id <connection name>
```

Answer (score 21):

You can just type

```
nmcli connection delete CONNECTION_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

To permanently remove:

```bsh
systemctl stop NetworkManager

rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/dummy-dummy0.nmconnection

systemctl startNetworkManager
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nmcli -f bridge con delete bridge-br0
```

This will delete it for you