# How do I delete ProtonVPN connections with Network Manager?

Tags: vpn, nmcli

On Ubuntu 18.04.  I upgraded my ProtonVPN CLI client from 2.2.6 to 3.7.2, which was a gigantic mistake. In troubleshooting the resulting issues, ProtonVPN support has asked me to delete connections related to ProtonVPN, but they haven't been able to tell me how.

These are my connections:

```
$ nmcli d
DEVICE          TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION 
wlp3s0          wifi      connected    WifiAP 
enp2s0          ethernet  unavailable  --         
pvpnroutintrf0  dummy     unmanaged    --         
lo              loopback  unmanaged    --         
proton0         tun       unmanaged    --
```

They want me to delete `pvpnroutintrf0` and `proton0`.  They suggested the commands

```
$ nmcli c delete pvpnroutintrf0 dummy
```

and

```
$ nmcli c delete proton0 tun
```

but these result in "unknown connection" errors:

```
$ nmcli c delete pvpnroutintrf0 dummy
Error: unknown connection 'pvpnroutintrf0'.
Error: unknown connection 'dummy'.
Error: cannot delete unknown connection(s): 'pvpnroutintrf0', 'dummy'.
```

```
$ nmcli c delete proton0 tun
Error: unknown connection 'proton0'.
Error: unknown connection 'tun'.
Error: cannot delete unknown connection(s): 'proton0', 'tun'.
```

I've tried using `sudo` with these, and it makes no difference.  I've also tried

```
$ nmcli c delete pvpnroutintrf0
$ nmcli c delete id pvpnroutintrf0
$ nmcli c delete id pvpnroutintrf0 dummy
$ nmcli connection delete pvpnroutintrf0
$ nmcli connection delete pvpnroutintrf0 dummy
$ nmcli connection delete id pvpnroutintrf0 dummy
```

They return the same "unknown connection" error.

[This Unix SE page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277555/how-to-delete-connection-by-name-via-network-manager) exists with a similar question but no relevant answers beyond what I've tried.  The man page for `nmcli` was similarly unhelpful, as one would expect.

How do I delete these two connections?

Comment: 1. Sorry for [offending your sense of grammatical purity](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/659301/3). Like many on this site, I am not a native speaker in English. - 2. By using this site you have agreed that others may [edit your post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/editing) to improve clarity, readability, add information, or remove unnecessary statements. Making the question less confrontative should certainly help to improve overall readability while at the same time making contributors more inclined to react to your request for assistance. I was hoping to help you that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have listed the output of `nmcli d` which lists the managed *devices*. However, you are trying to delete *connections* which are a different item for `nmcli`. From the man-page:

> NetworkManager stores all network configuration as "connections", which are collections of data (Layer2 details, IP addressing, etc.) that describe how to create or connect to a network. A connection is "active" when a device uses that connection's configuration to create or connect to a network.

If you look at `nmcli c show`, you will find output as in

```
NAME      UUID                                  TYPE             DEVICE
<name>    <some uuid>                           <type info>      <device>
```

The value of the `NAME` column is the expected argument to a `nmcli c delete` command. You should therefore use the connection names used by devices `pvpnroutintrf0` and `proton0` in your `delete` command to achieve what the ProtonVPN support suggested. (*Sometimes, these are chosen to coincide with device names, but it seems not to be the case in your setup.*)

Comment: This is exactly correct.  ProtonVPN support confused `nmcli c show` with `nmcli d` consistently and gave me the wrong commands to run until we got it sorted out.