# Why does a network connection not change from "unmanaged"?

Tags: vpn, nmcli

I'm a month into a disasterous upgrade of my ProtonVPN CLI client from 2.2.6 to 3.7.2 on Ubuntu 18.04, and the VPN still doesn't work (this question is related to my [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/659301/377345)).

Here is the current status of my devices:

```
$ nmcli d
DEVICE          TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
wlp3s0          wifi      connected     WifiAP
proton0         tun       disconnected  --         
enp2s0          ethernet  unavailable   --         
ipv6leakintrf0  dummy     unmanaged     --         
lo              loopback  unmanaged     --
```

ProtonVPN support has explained that they don't "support unmanaged connections", still not sure what that means.  They supplied me with the following commands to change this:

```
$ sudo nmcli dev set proton0 managed yes
```

This changed the `proton0` connection from "unmanaged" to "disconnected", as seen above.  Then I ran

```
$ sudo nmcli dev set ipv6leakintrf0 managed yes
```

and this did nothing.  It did not affect the status of `ipv6leakintrf0` in any way.

Why will this device refuse to change from "unmanaged"?

**Update**

According to [this page](https://www.ithands-on.com/2021/02/linux-101-networkmanager-unmanaged.html), having an entry in an `/etc/network/interfaces` file can make a device be unmanaged.

I can't find any reference to `ipv6leakintrf0` in any of these files, however, so I don't think this is the problem:

```
$ grep -IRF "ipv6" /etc/network/*
{no results}
```

Answer (score 4):

The default Ubuntu 18.04 Network Manager configuration includes a file `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf` with the directive

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan
```

which sets all devices that aren't 'wifi' or 'wwan' to be unmanaged.  Presumably this includes ProtonVPN's 'proton0' and 'ipv6leakintrf0' device profiles, which explains why I couldn't set these to be "managed".

From the NetworkManager [configuration man page](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-NetworkManager.conf/), you can almost piece together that NetworkManager constructs its configuration from the following sources, in order:

1. /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/
2. /run/NetworkManager/conf.d/
3. /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/
4. /etc/NetworkManager.conf
5. /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager-intern.conf

where later files override earlier files and users shouldn't edit the last two.  Within each of the three `conf.d/` directories, configuration is again constructed in list order (this is why filenames inside them begin with numbers -- to order them by priority).

The file that I assume sets my ProtonVPN device profiles to be unmanaged, `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf`, comes early in the priority listing and thus could easily be overwritten.  As far as I can tell, the only way to be certain whether or not it is overwritten is the unnecessarily user-hostile procedure of examining every file in every directory in the above listing while knowing exactly what each directive included there does in order to determine if it overrides the management status of something affected by the original directive

```
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan
```

I can't do this.  Instead, I grepped each file in the priority listing for "unmanaged-devices" to look for an explicit override of this exact directive.  I found none, so I'm going to assume that I can override the `unmanaged-devices` directive in `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf` by creating a higher-priority file `80-proton-vpn.conf` in the same directory.

I created the file `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/80-proton-vpn.conf` with contents

```
[device]
match-device=interface-name:proton0
managed=true

[device]
match-device=interface-name:ipv6leakintrf0
managed=true
```

which, based on my best ability to interpret the difficult NetworkManager documentation, should set the two ProtonVPN device profiles 'proton0' and 'ipv6leakintrf0' to "managed".

I restarted the `network-manager` service and attempted to connect to ProtonVPN.  The 'ipv6leakintrf0' device had already disappeared from the output of `nmcli d` during earlier troubleshooting, but the 'proton0' device remained "disconnected".  There is likely an additional error (or many), and I'll have to wait for additional guidance from ProtonVPN support before I can determine if the `80-proton-vpn.conf` file successfully allows these device profiles to be set to "managed".

**Update**

ProtonVPN declared that this is Ubuntu's problem, and they refuse to help me with it any more.  The only support I'm allowed for Ubuntu is AskUbuntu, which is predictably worthless.  So, I'm still eager for any other contributions which will help resolve this issue if anybody has any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed netplan? See netplan.io.
Netplan allows you to configure networkd and network-manager using YAML configuration files and a simple CLI. Comes enabled by default by Ubuntu server.

https://www.linux.com/topic/distributions/how-use-netplan-network-configuration-tool-linux/

That article will give you a hint to where you can go.

Comment: Could you [edit] and include some relevant details from the link?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is NetworkManager doesn't manage these devices due to whatever the reason. This post helped me https://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-device-not-managed

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/427409)